# redirecting to root rather than controller/edit for password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

NOTE: I'm not using Devise.

I'm implementing a password reset action and I have the controller Password_Resets with the following edit action:

```
  def edit
  end

  def update
    puts "I'm in the update!!"
    if params[:user][:password].empty?
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to recipes_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

When I'm trying to run through it, I put in the appropriate URL and I get the following response:

```
Started GET "/password_resets/igArFj9sYLt1J6k6Y2BjSg/edit?email=maggie%40example.com" for ::1 at 2016-04-20 21:49:58 -0500
Processing by PasswordResetsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"maggie@example.com", "id"=>"igArFj9sYLt1J6k6Y2BjSg"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT 1  [["email", "maggie@example.com"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :valid_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Why is it redirecting to localhost rather than the view app/views/password_resets/edit?? I can't seem to figure out a good way to "debug" this or see what's going on.

NOTE: I made that view incredibly simple to make sure it wasn't redirecting.

This is the view app/views/password_resets/edit:

```
 <h1>This is my edit view </h1>
```

**EDIT::: SOLUTION**

So I was just an idiot. Essentially I have a validated user command that checked if the user was authenticated and the user was not. Therefore I need some more error handling.

Thanks you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your validations:

```
Filter chain halted as :valid_user rendered or redirected
```

I'm assuming you are calling this at the top of your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can see in your web server logs:
`Filter chain halted as :valid_user rendered or redirected`
It's mean you have `before_filter` or `before_action` in a controller. 
This filter is just ruby method - `def valid_user` and obvious that it contains a condition with redirect.
You need to debug this method.

You can read more about controller filters [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)